# php GET variable mismatch

Tags: php, variables, get, mismatch

I have an android app that uses a URL Connection.  The latter part of the URL string is;

```
./upload_data.php?id=SC1495&image=%3FPNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%02X%00%00%01%15%08%02%00%00%00%3F*%0C%3F%00%00%00%03sBIT%05%06%053%0B%3F%3F%00%00%01%3FIDATx%3F%3F%3F1%01%00%00%00%3F%3FOm%0D%0F%3F%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%3F7%3F%26%00%01%40%3F%27%13%00%00%00%00IEND%3FB%60%3F&imagename=bob&imagetime=20140806+121507
```

When I put this into the browser and use $_GET['image'], it returns the following;
`?PNG  IHDRX?*?sBIT3???IDATx???1??Om ??7?&@?'IEND?B`?`

I am not decoding anything, I just want to get the string with all the %00 etc.

Can someone enlighten me as to why this would be happening?

Comment: What is there in the `upload_data.php`? Files should be sent using POST and not using GET!

Comment: $_GET will decode the url, so you can re-encode it to get the %00 characters back etc. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_GET['image']` is returning the correct string. The characters in the url are mainly `%00` which is equal to NULL in URL encoding. If you want to keep the characters you can use `rawurlencode()`

```
$img = $_GET['image'];

echo rawurlencode($img);
```

Or just

```
echo urlencode($_GET['image'])
```

This will convert the characters you've got back to their url encoded form

Comment: What you are suggesting is technically correct. But as a design the data should be url encoded from the source and you should not be re-encoding recieved data.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao Yeah, agreed

Answer (score 0):

remove special charactors

```
if ($_GET['image'] != ""){
    $img = htmlspecialchars($_GET['image']);
    echo "<h3>".$_GET['image']."</h3><br><img src='http://yoursite.com/images/".$_GET['image']."'>";
}
else {
    exit ("No image here =(");
}
```